# use Nginx in elastic beanstalk substitute of apache2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

By default elastic beanstalk use apache2.
But I want to use Nginx. I search but I can not find a suitable way.
How can I do that?

Comment: Which platform and Amazon LInux version? Usually nginx is used.

Comment: I choose PHP and it has a default image that uses apache2

Comment: If yo use Amazon Linux 2 (current version of EB), it should be nginx, not apache. Are you sure you use AL2?

Comment: yes. I try to remove httpd and It works

Comment: Glad to here. So changing to AL2 worked? If so, I can make an answer for future reference?

Comment: yes. please write your answer amazon Linux 2  use Nginx 
can I have your email or Linkedin account for further questions?

Comment: Thanks. Answer added. For now, I would recommending posting issues on SO. I monitor it daily. Also, if I'm not able to provide help, others on SO may also assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

**Amazon Linux 1** (AL1) uses `apache2`. However, **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) uses `nginx`.

Therefore, the **solution** was to upgrade to AL2 instead of using AL1.